# Why does LEN( char(32) ) = 0 in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wanted to write a function to count the number of delimiters or any substring (which could be a space) in a string of text, throwing a hack error if the delimiter was null or empty:

```
if len(@lookfor)=0 or @lookfor is null return Cast('substring must not be null or empty' as int)
```

But if the function is called with @lookfor = ' ' that trips the error.

I am aware of DATALENGTH().  Just curious why a single space is treated as "trailing" if there's nothing before it.

Comment: Interesting observation. If I were you I'd use IF NULLIF(@lookfor,CHAR(32)) IS NULL RETURN...

Comment: Wouldn't that do the opposite of what I want to do?  I want to allow the space.

Comment: Ah, sorry, got mixed up. You're right. Then maybe replace CHAR(32) to something else (just in the condition)? IF NULLIF(REPLACE(@lookfor,CHAR(32),'|'),'') IS NULL RETURN...

Comment: It's "trailing" because if you look at the end of the string, there it is. Having nothing before it doesn't change that. [`DataLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql) does not exclude trailing blanks. For Unicode strings you can use `DataLength( UnicodeStringExpression ) / DataLength( N'#' )` to get the length in characters. In general `DataLength( Left( Coalesce( StringExpression, '#' ), 1 ) )` will return the number of bytes per character.

Answer (score 3):

> I am aware of DATALENGTH(). Just curious why a single space is treated
>   as "trailing" if there's nothing before it.

It's trailing because it's at the end of the string. It's also leading since it's the at the beginning.

> > But if the function is called with @lookfor = '' that trips the error

Something that messes a lot of people up with SQL is how '' = ' '; Note this query:

```
DECLARE @blank VARCHAR(10) = '', @space VARCHAR(10) = CHAR(32);
SELECT CASE WHEN @blank = @space THEN 'That the...!?!?' END;
```

You can change @space to CHAR(32)+CHAR(32)+.... and @space and @blank will still be equal.

Complicating things a little more note that the `DATALENGTH` for a blank/empty value is 0 when it's a VARCHAR(N) but the DATALENGTH is N when for CHAR(N) values. In other words, 
`SELECT DATALENGTH(CAST('' AS CHAR(1)))` returns 1 and `SELECT DATALENGTH(CAST('' AS CHAR(10)))` returns 10.

That means that if your delimiter variable is say, CHAR(1) - that will mess you up.  Here's the function for you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountDelimiters(@string VARCHAR(8000), @delimiter VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT DCount = MAX(DATALENGTH(@string)-LEN(REPLACE(@string,@delimiter,'')))
WHERE  DATALENGTH(@delimiter) > 0;
```

Note that @delimter is VARCHAR(1) and **NOT** a CHAR datatype.

The formula to count delimiters in @string is:

`DATALENGTH(@string)-LEN(REPLACE(@string,@delimiter,''))` 
or

`(DATALENGTH(@string)-LEN(REPLACE(@string,@delimiter,'')))/DATALENGTH(@delimiter)` when dealing with delimiters longer than 1`.

`WHERE DATALENGTH(@delimiter) > 0` will force the function to ignore a NULL or blank value. This is known as a *Startup Predicate*.

Putting a MAX around `DATALENGTH(@string)-LEN(REPLACE(@string,@delimiter,''))` forces the function to rerturn a NULL value in the event you pass it a blank or NULL value.

This will return 10 for the number of spaces in my string:

```
SELECT f.DCount FROM dbo.CountDelimiters('one space  two spaces   three   ', CHAR(32)) AS f;
```

Against a table you would use the function like this (note that I'm counting the number of times the letter "A" appears:

```
-- Sample Strings
DECLARE @table TABLE (SomeText VARCHAR(36));
INSERT @table VALUES('ABCABC'),('XXX'),('AAA'),(''),(NULL);

SELECT      t.SomeText, f.DCount    
FROM        @table                               AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.CountDelimiters(t.SomeText, 'A') AS f;
```

**Which returns:**

```
SomeText                             DCount
------------------------------------ -----------
ABCABC                               2
XXX                                  0
AAA                                  3
                                     0
NULL                                 NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If a string has a chacacter at the end, it is considered trailing, even if there are no other characters before it. Same for logic regarding leading characters.

So `' '` can be considered an empty string (`''`) having a trailing space.

When I started using SQL, I also noticed the behavior that the LEN function ignores trailing spaces. And I think (but I am not sure) that is has to do with the fact that LEN should probably also behave "correctly" when used with CHAR/NCHAR values. Unlike VARCHAR/NVARCHAR, the CHAR/NCHAR values have a fixed width and will be filled with trailing spaces automatically. So when you put value `'abc'` in a field/variable of type CHAR(5), the value will become `'abc  '`, but the LEN function will still "correctly" return 3 in that case.

I consider this just to be a strange quirk of SQL.

Remark:

The `DATALENGTH` function will not ignore trailing spaces in VARCHAR/NVARCHAR values. But note that `DATALENGTH` will return the **size in bytes** of the field's value. So if you use unicode data (NCHAR/NVARCHAR), the `DATALENGTH` function will return 6 for value `N'abc'`, because each unicode character in SQL Server uses 2 bytes!

Comment: Yes, DATALENGTH(N'abc')=6 and DATALENGTH('abc')=3

Comment: I consider it an example of the programmers being a little too helpful.   That's what TRIM is for.

Comment: `declare @x nchar(3); set @x = N'abc'; select 1 where len(@x)=3`    It's byzantine.